# Looking to migrate from 2003 to Exchange 2010, what are best practices for importing PSTs?"

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook, import

I'm looking at ways to import PST files into Exchange (specifically Exchange 2010) during an Exchange 2003 to 2010 migration. Any handy tips and tricks anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Import-Mailbox`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629586.aspx) to import PST files into Exchange mailboxes.

But why aren't you just migrating mailboxes directly between your Exchange servers?

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I want to get rid of PST files completely once we have migrated to Exchange 2010.

Comment: Oh, so you're looking into merging already-existing PSTs with actual mailbox contents... fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010, you can follow either of the two methods:

- EAC method
- PowerShell method

In EAC method (more preferred), follow steps to import PST files to Exchange 2010

1. Get access to EAC with Admin credentials.
2. Grant permission of Import to perform Import process.
3. Go to **Recipients>> More (...)>>Import PST Option**
4. Provide **UNC shared file path** of the .pst file
5. Select the Mailbox to import the PST file.
6. Click **Finish** and the PST file will be imported to the selected User mailbox.

For a detailed description, **Visit [Link](https://exchange-server-guide.blogspot.com/2018/03/export-exchange-2010-mailbox-to-pst.html)...**

In PowerShell Command, Follow below steps:

1. Grant permission of **Import** to perform Import process.
   Use the following command for granting permission

**New-ManagementRoleAssignment -Role "Mailbox Import Export" -User "User_Mailbox_Name"**

2. Execute following command to perform **Import process**

**New-MailboxImportRequest -Mailbox “User_Mailbox_Name” -FilePath “UNC_shared_File_Path”**

3. Execute below command to get the status of the on-going import process

**Get-MailboxImportRequest | Get-MailboxImportRequestStatistics**

If any doubt occurs while performing the above PowerShell commands, Visit [**Exchange 2010 Import PST Mailbox via PowerShell Command**](https://windowsinstructed.com/exchange-2010-import-pst-mailbox-powershell-command/)

Hope this will resolve your problem. Please feel free to ask anything which is not understood or taking you to wrong way.

Thanks, Adwin John